# uWSGI: I got problem with threaded mode

Tags: multithreading, nginx, uwsgi

If I use uWSGI without threaded mode, it works fine. But my original server run with Apache ServerLimit 1, threaded-mode.
It can handle concurrent connection, but my uWSGI can't (because worker only 1, I think).
So I try to open threaded mode, but I will get 502 Bad Gateway error message from nginx.

My log showed me:
uwsgi: Modules/gcmodule.c:277: visit_decref: Assertion `gc->gc.gc_refs != 0' failed.

I have no idea about what's wrong, How can I make it work?
Thanks.

Here is my configuration:

```
[uwsgi]

show-config=True
socket=:8002
pidfile=/var/run/unicorn_uwsgi.pid
daemonize=/root/logs/unicorn_uwsgi.log
vacuum=True
enable-threads=True
threads=40
processes=1
env=QTDIR=/root/lib/qt
env=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/root/lib/qt/lib
env=DISPLAY=:99
env=XAUTHORITY=/root/webapps/xvfb/Xauthority.xvfb
module=WSGI
home=/root/webapps/unicorn
pythonpath=/root/Source/Server/Unicorn
chdir=/root/Source/Server/Unicorn
```

I use nginx as HTTP server, here is configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8002;
    }
}
```

OS: CentOS 6.0, CPU:  AMD Athlon(tm) XP 2500+, RAM: 2G

Python 2.6.5 (default), uWSGI: 0.9.8.2, nginx: 0.8.54

Comment: Have you compiled a custom python, or are you using the centos6 default one ? Which uWSGI and Python version ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with the centos6 supplied PyQt4 ? (from your config it looks like you are using pyqt, and there are various reports on this kind of problem in pyqt)

Comment: I didn't use PyQT4, but I wrote my own QT4.7 application using C++ as a fork process. When request comes, I fork my application to get some data by QT4.7.2 than return as response. This works fine in Apache+mod_wsgi threaded mode.

Comment: i was not able to reproduce your error, so it is something in the app that triggers it. Can you post the list of third party modules you use ?

Comment: These days I carefully test that, I found a simple django application won't crash with my configuration. But my application will get "uwsgi: Modules/gcmodule.c:277: visit_decref: Assertion `gc->gc.gc_refs != 0' failed." this problem. That might be not caused by third-party modules. But I can't figure out what's wrong in my application because it is not caused in the same place. Only one thing I can sure is all work fine in Apache+mod_wsgi threads mode. How can I to diagnose this problem?